# Converting a row of a pandas dataframe into a dataframe itself (instead of a series)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that I'm iterating over, like so

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
       process(row)
```

The function *process* takes the argument and itself does an iterrows() on it. It does this because it is normally passed a dataframe. However, I'd like to pass a single row to *process* and still have it function normally. The problem is that *row* is a Series, and not a dataframe. And Series can not be iterated over with an .iterrows() method. I tried converting the row to a dataframe like so

`row = row.to_frame()`

but that doesn't seem to preserve the indices, columns, etc.

Is there a way to do this easily? Or should I re-write the *process* function to be able to handle a single Series/row?

Comment: Why do `iterrows()` in the first place? You can do `DataFrame.apply(lambda x: process(x), axis=1)` and then you can process the row from there.

Comment: It might be more costly but you can try something like: `for i in range(len(df)): process(df.iloc[[i]])` double brackets will make sure it returns a DataFrame.

Comment: @AlexS Funnily enough, iterrows is faster than apply in some instances. At its heart, apply is just a python loop with overhead.

Comment: @AlexS, if the function process were simple, I would just do something like that. But process is actually a class (that uses another class) that optimizes over a very complex model using minimization routines. Iterrows() is a minor computational expense in relation to everything else that's happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can transpose the output of `to_frame`:

```
s.to_frame().T
```

That said, this seems a strange thing to require, a refactor of `process` may be a good idea. But perhaps you can get away with chunkifying into smaller dataframes:

```
for chunk in np.array_split(df, 50):  # 50 chunks
    process(chunk)
```

Comment: Doing the transpose works. Thanks Andy! I would refactor _process_, but it's actually a very complicated class (that uses another class) and not a simple function. I'm simply coding up some debugging code right now, and this simple approach is all I need for that.